# Products of manifolds and locally ringed spaces (over $\mathbb{R}$) coincide?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds. The cartesian product $M\times N$ has a natural manifold structure. Moreover, $M$ and $N$ can be seen as locally ringed spaces over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}$ and the fiber product (in this category) $M\times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}}N$ always exists.

**I wonder if both products coincide or not.** (However, I know that they don't if we take the fiber product on the category of ringed spaces. This is because, in this case, the structure sheaf of the product is the tensor product of the structure sheaves.)

What about more general limits? And other kinds of manifolds?

Comment: A construction of products of locally ringed spaces is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033675/does-the-category-of-locally-ringed-spaces-have-products) by Hanno Becker.

Comment: Dear @TimCampion, I actually knew that construction and it inspired my question. But I don't see why it solves my doubt

Comment: Oh for sure it's not an answer, that's why it was just a comment. Have you tried working out what Hanno's construction gives you in the case at hand? It probably simplifies to some extent at least.

Comment: I did, in fact. But I couldn't go very far, even in the underlying set. For example, the fiber product of two schemes over $\mathbb{R}$ does *not* have the cartesian product as underlying set. So we have to use somewhere that $M$ and $N$ are manifolds. I just don't know where.

Comment: I don't believe that the germ $\mathcal O_{\mathbb R^2,0}$ could be obtained algebraically from the algebraic tensor product $\mathcal O_{\mathbb R,0}\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathcal O_{\mathbb R,0}$.

Comment: @Z.M and why would that need to be the case?

Comment: This is the simplest case of the product of two real lines. You look at the construction of the product of locally ringed spaces, and a stalk of the structure sheaf is essentially a localization of the tensor product, while I was trying to say that a stalk on the real plane does not look like that.

Comment: Essentially I believe that you need more data than the ring structure, kinda "locally $C^\infty$-ringed spaces", see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/C%5E%E2%88%9E-ring

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you think of manifolds as $C^\infty$-schemes.

(Joyces's book on the subject is probably the most accessible reference, but you could try the original paper by Dubuc.)  You can see a hint of this fact in Moerdijk and Reyes' *Models of infinitesimal analysis* where they prove that the $C^\infty$-ring of smooth functions on the product $M\times N$ is the coproduct of the $C^\infty$-rings of functions on $M$ and on $N$. And Spec sends coproducts to products...